# How to update a Panel when user selects a drop down choice in Wicket?

Tags: ajax, wicket

I would like to know how to update a panel when we select a drop down chioce values, that is in onUpdate() method.

My custom panel has AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable.

Below is Panel and drop down components code. When user selects date, I want to replace my entire Panel. Currently I have commened that target.addComponent code, but I want to have implementation here. Any suggestions?

```
List<DealHistory> dealHistoryList = ServicesCaller
            .getAllDealHistoryRecords();
    DealHistoryTablePanel dealHistoryTablePanel = new DealHistoryTablePanel(
            "deal_history_table_panel", dealHistoryList);
    dealHistoryTablePanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    add(dealHistoryTablePanel);

    IModel<List<? extends String>> dateChoices = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<? extends String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> getObject() {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Last 3 months");
            list.add("Last 6 months");
            return list;
        }
    };

    final DropDownChoice<String> datesDropDown = new DropDownChoice<String>(
            "dates", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selectedDate"),
            dateChoices);
    datesDropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            //target.addComponent(dealHistoryTablePanel);
        }
    });
    add(datesDropDown);
```

Comment: I think you should accept Don Roby's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track.  The basic thing that will make it happen is having the

```
target.addComponent(dealHistoryTablePanel);
```

exactly where you have it, in an `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior`.

You'll also likely want to change the model in your `DealHistoryTablePanel`, probably by replacing the list it contains with one gotten by a different call to your service.  To say anything more explicit, I'd have to see the code for `DealHistoryTablePanel`.

An [example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket14/ajax/choice.1) showing the updating of one `DropDownChoice` after the selction of one is instructive, though of course the component it updates is different.

Comment: I have found the problem, now it is working as expected. But I am seeing one more issue with navigation bar message and numbers that it shows. 

First time when I load page, it shows "showing 1 to 10 of 50", now I clicked next arrow link and it shows "showing 11 to 20 of 50". 

After this, I changed my drop down chioce to get another list from data base. I am expecting that my table should display "showing 1 to 10 of 50", but instead it is shows "showing 11 to 20 of 50" (this is the last display message before changing drop down). 
 
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @goutham: There's likely some paging data in the table mechanism you're using that needs to be reset when you change lists.  Post your DealHistoryTablePanel code and I might be able to help.

Comment: I found the solution for this. That is, calling table.setCurrentPage(0); after drop down value change. Thanks anyway for looking into this.